# MapView Problems

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm attempting to make an app that will swap to MapView when you hit the settings button and click on "Swap to Map" However everytime it force close. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. My teacher didn't explain how to do it all and told us that we could figure it out on the internet...Nice of her right?

Here is the Class that seems to be having the problem.

```
  package com.example.zip.code;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;

public class OpenMap extends Activity {
    private MapController mapController;
     private LocationManager locationManager;
      private String provider;
      double lat;
      double lng;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Get Mapping Controllers etc
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapController = mapView.getController();

        // Center on Current Position
        mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                                                  (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6)));
        mapController.setZoom(11);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.mapsettings, menu);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle item selection
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.zipswap:
                  swapToZip();
                  return true;
              default:
                  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }

      public void swapToZip(){
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
      }
}
```

This is the corresponding XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="ADD YOUR API KEY HERE"
        />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Class that leads into the Class that is causing the problem.
    package com.example.zip.code;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

     private TextView latituteField;
      private TextView longitudeField;
      private TextView zipField;
      private TextView cityField;
      private LocationManager locationManager;
      private String provider;
      double lat;
      double lng;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
        zipField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        cityField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
          System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
          onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
          latituteField.setText("Location not available");
          longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
        }


      }

      /* Request updates at startup */
      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
      }

      /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = (location.getLatitude());
        lng = (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String zip = address.getPostalCode();
                String city = address.getLocality();
                zipField.setText(zip);
                cityField.setText(city);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.zipsettings, menu);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle item selection
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.mapswap:
                  System.out.println("Derp");
                  swapToMap();
                  return true;
              default:
                  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }

      public void swapToMap(){
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OpenMap.class);
          startActivity(i);
      }

}
```

And this is the XML that corresponds to the first class.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/current"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/Header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/gps"
        android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:textSize="@dimen/Header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textColor="@color/Green"
        android:textSize="@dimen/Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/zip"
        android:textColor="@color/Green"
        android:textSize="@dimen/Header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Latitude: "
        android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:text="Longitute: "
        android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my LogCat from debugging it on my phone.

```
  10-25 23:00:05.610: I/System.out(28034): Provider network has been selected.
    10-25 23:00:06.438: D/libEGL(28034): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
    10-25 23:00:06.438: D/libEGL(28034): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    10-25 23:00:06.446: D/libEGL(28034): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    10-25 23:00:06.453: D/libEGL(28034): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
    10-25 23:00:06.711: D/OpenGLRenderer(28034): Enabling debug mode 0
    10-25 23:00:13.125: I/System.out(28034): Derp
    10-25 23:00:13.321: E/dalvikvm(28034): Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.MapView', referenced from method com.example.zip.code.OpenMap.onCreate
    10-25 23:00:13.321: W/dalvikvm(28034): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 438 (Lcom/google/android/maps/MapView;) in Lcom/example/zip/code/OpenMap;
    10-25 23:00:13.321: D/dalvikvm(28034): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x002b
    10-25 23:00:13.321: D/dalvikvm(28034): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0c01 at 0x43 in Lcom/example/zip/code/OpenMap;.onCreate
    10-25 23:00:13.328: D/AndroidRuntime(28034): Shutting down VM
    10-25 23:00:13.328: W/dalvikvm(28034): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aad210)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zip.code/com.example.zip.code.OpenMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1879)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at com.example.zip.code.OpenMap.onCreate(OpenMap.java:29)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4539)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2013)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    ... 11 more
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.MapView
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    10-25 23:00:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(28034):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Extend your `OpenMap` class by `MapActivity` if its a mapView class..

Comment: if you are running in emulator create emulator with google apis

Comment: did you add uses-library as google map library in manifest??

Comment: @Kalpesh How exactly do I do that. She has literally taught us nothing of this sort.

Comment: @todaroa you should add the google map library by selecting the project and right click on it and then select property and in that go to buildpath and select the library .

Comment: have you downloaded the googlemap api ? coz emulator should have the googlemap

Comment: The <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> is like this, you can refer these two sites
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview  AND  http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: Alright, I tried extending it by MapActivity and putting in the library but still no success

Comment: Still, you're getting those exceptions? Okay have you tried [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080677/mapview-problems#comment17771609_13080677)

Comment: SEE my ans..BTW @todaroa im also Android Teacher i would never like that student make this kind of mistakes

Comment: My teacher never taught us anything of this sort. She just threw this onto us. We just learned how to use an ActionListener in class.

Comment: Can the Target Build make a difference.

Comment: @todaroa ya can understand your feeling

Comment: I ended up getting it to get past the errors but now It just goes to a black screen, and I don't think its inflating the new layout.

Answer (score 0):

pleace check your manifest.xml file.
if you are not add use user library filein application then you can add this user library in your application manifest file

like this

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
<activity android:name="com.android.calendar.AgendaActivity"></activity>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend the `MapActivity` instead of `Activity`
2. And in Manifest , just check you have implemented the following lines,

   <    uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

   And you need to give permission for INTERNET

   <  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
3. Another one is MapKey,

Get your `MapKey` for your debug certificates `MD5 API key` from google.

Comment: Can that cause the problems of a force close?

Comment: @todaroa: I guess the MapActivity extending is the only problem.
It may cause force close. We cant say that , only these things will give force close. Many cases it will be force close only.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.MapView : This might be the reason of <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> declaration missing in the Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

just add following line into your menifest..it might works

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

and from your CML it seems like you have not added API key..

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="ADD YOUR API KEY HERE"             // here your API key which is provided by google map to you
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run your app with emulator then, check whether you've created the emulator's target with `Google's Api` If not just create one new `Android Virtual Deice (AVD)` with target of `Google's Api` Otherwise, you can't able to run your `MapView` related app in your emulator. For ex -

[image http://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Screen-Shot-2011-08-24-at-9.45.55-AM.png](http://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Screen-Shot-2011-08-24-at-9.45.55-AM.png)

Generate your `API` key for your `MapView` You can able to know how to create api key in second tutorial link below. And, make sure that where you're using `MapView` component in your class, you've to extend that class by `MapActivity` instead of `Activity` Don't forget to add below things in your manifest file -

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

above one is for your `mapView` library. And, below one is for internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Anyway have a look at below tutorials. It may helps you -

1. [MapView Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview)
2. [How to use Google maps in android](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/253-how-to-use-google-maps-in-android)